# Google Material You: How can we use the same Color Accent than system+Google Apps?

Tags: android, material-design, material-you, accent-color

I have read the "documentation" to find the reference to accent color: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color#system_accent1_0

But after implementing it in my application, I am not happy with the results and really like the Google implementation. (See screenshot below)

I have tried to display all colors in a sample application (the one on the left) and cannot find the same color than Google apps on the right (Phone, Gmail, Drive)

Is Google implementing a custom / proprietary implementation? Did I missed something?

Thank a lot for any help to find the right colors to use for my ActionBar, FAB, and other items.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all most of the colors have transparency so it will be affected by background color, in their implementation, they used a dark brown color, which will affect some colors if there is transparency.
2. Some of the colors are identical see the image.

[image: legends]

Comment: Ok, it looks like I missed a lot of things in the colors, it looks obvious now.. Thanks a lot!